# Web-scraping return empty values: possible protected site

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with web-scraping from [www.albumoftheyear.org](http://www.albumoftheyear.org), but in my code I can only get an empty df.

I don't know if the site is protected with some cloudflare and if this is a cause or I'm making a mistake with the selected tags.

The basic idea is to iterate through the pages and collect the data (title, year, genre) from the albums and create a df (pandas).

Here is the code developed:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.albumoftheyear.org/list/1500-rolling-stones-500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-2020/{}'

title = []
data  = []
genre = []

for i in range(1,11):
 soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(i)).content, "html.parser")
 album_lists = soup.find_all(class_='albumListRow')
 for album_list in album_lists:
  album_title = album_list.find('h2',{'class':'albumListTitle'}).find('a').text
  album_data = album_list.find('div', {'class':'albumListDate'}).text
  album_genre = album_list.find('div', {'class': 'albumListGenre'}).find('a').text
  title.append(album_title)
  data.append(album_data)
  genre.append(album_genre)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(title,data,genre)), columns=['title', 'data','genre'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution using selenium. Note you need to have the webdriver for your browser on your system. I am using Chrome and the chromedriver can be gotten from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Yes you need both the browser and the driver.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\**YOUR PATH**\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(r"https://www.albumoftheyear.org/list/1500-rolling-stones-500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-2020/{}")

title_list = []
date_list  = []
genre_list = []

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "centerContent"))
    )
    albumlistrow = element.find_elements_by_class_name('albumListRow')
    for a in albumlistrow:
        title = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListTitle')
        date = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListDate')
        try:
            genre = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListGenre')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        title_list.append(title.text)
        date_list.append(date.text)
        genre_list.append(genre.text)

finally:
    driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(title_list,date_list,genre_list)), columns=['title', 'data','genre'])
df.head()
```

output

```
    title                                               data                genre
0   500. Arcade Fire - Funeral                          September 14, 2004  Indie Rock
1   499. Rufus & Chaka Khan - Ask Rufus                 January 19, 1977    Soul
2   498. Suicide - Suicide                              December 28, 1977   Synth Punk
3   497. Various Artists - The Indestructible Beat...   January 1, 1985     Synth Punk
4   496. Shakira - Dónde Están los Ladrones?            September 29, 1998  Pop Rock
```

If you do not want the albumListRank change this line from

```
title_list.append(title.text)
```

to

```
title_list.append(title.text[4:])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you are trying to *scrape* a dynamic website.**

'requests' is good for scraping static pages but for dynamic sites like this, you have to use a **selenium webdriver**.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because of Cloudflare. If you add `print(soup.text)` to your script, you can see that Cloudflare is blocking you. To circumvent this, you can add headers.

```
#theese are basic headers which will get you past cloudflare
userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'#user agent
accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
referer = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=album+songs&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'#this is also really important for cloudflare bypass
acceptLanguage = 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
dnt = '1'

#define headers
headers = {'user-agent':userAgent,'accept':accept,'referer':referer,'accept-language':acceptLanguage,'dnt':dnt}

#lastly when making requests use the following request
requests.get(url.format(i),headers=headers)
```

Also adding a delay between each request will help with the cloudflare. One second minimum.

If this dosent help make sure you are using a home network, not a shared network. (eg. school/work)